# Browser doesn't return If-None-Match header

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, https, http-headers

i am trying to implement caching for dynamic API calls where data is near-static. The approach i have taken is using the **ETag** and returning an ETag header for a Web API response headers. However, Browser doesn't seems to return the "if-None-Match" header at all for me to validate the subsequent calls.

Please note that i am using https and i have a valid SSL installed. Anyone had this issue and potential clues?

[image]

Comment: I am facing this same issue. I modified my response header on server end. But I am still not able to receive back the if-none-match. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Found the root cause of the issue, It was due to the wrong cache-headers being sent by the server particularly **Cache-Control: no-store**

After changing the response headers, Browser is now able to send the **If-None-Match** request header.

My current response header is as below which is good enough to request the browser to re-validate it.

[image]